# How to setting TTL on Redis with Apache NiFi RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

Through Apache NiFi v1.10.0,it has a controller-service,which type is RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService . It has a property which name is TTL ,i hava set it 10 secs,but it  does not work .[image] [image][image][image]

Comment: What is the second screenshot showing?

Comment: i use notify processor to set a key in redis,the second screenshot show the key's TTL in redis,i think the TTL is 10 secs @BryanBende

Comment: It looks like the TTL is not being used in the "replace" method of the Redis DMC service and that method is what is being called by Wait/Notify so that is why it is staying as -1, this is a bug that should be fixed

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7432

Comment: thanks for your reply,wish this problem will be solved soon

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and [has been resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7432). The solution to this issue is to make sure that you are running NiFi 1.12.0 or newer.